# HD Full Phpmyadmin don't work

Tags: php, mysql, centos-6

This is the third time I Have the same problem, in the last two times a guy solved to me and said the problem is a "BIG phpmyadmin or mysql log", the problem is: My phpmyadmin stop working and my Hard drive is full, when I use the df -h command I receive this:

```
[root@ns524341 var]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   19G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         16G  228K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         16G  228K   16G   1% /dev
/dev/md3        1.8T  214G  1.5T  13% /home
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/md2         20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key`
```

I'm using Centos 6.8, anybody can help me?

Comment: I Found a tutorial who said to delete the binary log but first I stopped my mysql and now they don't start more...

Comment: who exactly was "a guy" to you?

Comment: A programmer That was my friend

Comment: which tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You will get all sorts of strange problems if your disk is full, because there's no way for a program to fix this itself, it will just stop.

You need to find that big log file somehow - do you still have access to a working terminal? If so, a command like this will find the biggest files

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n | tail -10 | cut -f2 | xargs -I{} du -sh {}
```

To avoid this problem happening in future, set up logrotate
https://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-logrotate-on-redhat-linux

Comment: I Think I Found, the problem is the binary log:    12784848 -rwx------. 1 mysql mysql 13078888448 Aug 28 11:58 ibdata1I stopped my mysqld using the command(service mysqld stop)but now I Can't start they to delete the binary files, why?
They don't start because the HD is full? How can I delete the binary files out of mysql?